# Percentage/Probability based on distance, high percentage for low value

Tags: probability, percentages

Let's say there's three objects `a, b, c` and one goal `x`. I have the distances of all the three objects to the goal `x`:

```
a -> x: 2   
b -> x: 8   
c -> x: 18
```

I now want to **calculate the percentage or probability of which object is closer to the target** (and thus has the highest probability of reaching it). I already tried to sum the distances and calculate percentages based on this sum, so eg. $\frac{2}{28}$ for a, but this gives a low percentage (7,14%) for a small distance, while I would like to have a high percentage for a low distance. I thus would need a way to 'reverse' this percentage. Subtracting it from 1 of course doesn't work since they would no longer sum to 1 (100%).

So in the end, I would like to **get something like this as a result**:

```
a: 70%
b: 25%
c: 5%
```

I already looked into Softmax and Sigmoid, but is there nothing more simple for this? I've been breaking my head on this for 2 hours already and can't figure it out! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the reciprocals of the distances?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Well, you could invert the numbers.  Starting with $\{\frac 12, \frac 18, \frac 1{18}\}$ you sum to get $\frac {49}{72}$.  Of that, $\frac 12$ is $73.47\%$ and so on.

Comment: This is actually a very nice idea! Thank you @lulu and herb steinberg (sorry can only tag 1 person) for this suggestion! Only issue is with distance 0 of course, but I'll build a small case for this to avoid errors.

Comment: Extra question/note: would it be possible to kind of weigh this in one or another way? Eg: 1 and 4 might be extremely far away from each other and thus the percentage for 1 should be higher than with the current formula? (in this case, 1 would give 0.8 and 4 would give 0.2, but let's say eg. you want 1 to be 0.98 and 4 0.02)